# Phantomjs no render

Tags: phantomjs

I work on a small project with PhantomJS to make screenshot

I use the standard script (http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) everything works perfectly

but if I change the url (this url :https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pomme&direction=next&oldid=46779461) screenshot does not work
I do not understand why it does not work...

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pomme&direction=next&oldid=46779461', function() {
    page.render('github2.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I use "phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx" , I have quickly try to add  onConsoleMessage, onError, onResourceError, onResourceTimeout and try your exemple : No error (but no screenshot ;) ) I will try again tomorrow more seriously (in France it is late)

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the issue and it seems like only that single page doesn't work.

Looks like that lemon-loving troll added so many "OOOOO"s that it broke the layout to the point that phantomjs is suiciding and refusing to cooperate.

That's my conclusion. My advice for today is to point your scripts to literally anything else.

Comment: OK, I had seen that, but I didn't think it was the problem because 
phantomjs can generate a very big/large screenshot

Comment: @Bob'sJellyfish For some reason, for me a functional wikipedia history page yields a very long image already with alot of white at the bottom: 1117x27123 (!) I have eyeballed that all these OOOOs would need a width circa 500 times of 1117 to be contained. If at any point in the phantomjs implementation the image is held in memory in its entirety in uncompressed 24bit rgb form, this would need a total of 1117*27123*500*3 = 42.3 GB of RAM to pull off.